# Why not store a phone number as 5 columns: country code, area code, prefix, line number and extension?

Tags: database-design

I'm working with data that was originally stored in an oracle database as a varchar2(12) bytes with the dashes (123-456-7890). There was no validation done originally and people stored all kinds of bad data. In the future I thought it might be a good idea to just store each part of the phone number into separate columns. Is this bad for performance though?

- HOME_PHONE_CON Number(1)
- HOME_PHONE_AREA Number(3)
- HOME_PHONE_PREF Number(3)
- HOME_PHONE_LINE Number(4)
- HOME_PHONE_EXT Number(4)

Answer (score 0):

=== Your table ===

If you store the data in 5 separate columns
then when user input 123-456-7890, it will be like this

```
HOME_PHONE_CON | HOME_PHONE_AREA | HOME_PHONE_PREF | HOME_PHONE_LINE | HOME_PHONE_EXT
null | 123 | 456 | 7890 | null
```

(I'm not in the US so apologize for the wrong format)

then someone have to search for a customer/user with this number
they will input "123-456-7890" or "1234567890"

You will have to

1. Split the input into **5 parts**
2. Query with multiple condition like - **where HOME_PHONE_CON like ('%part1%') and all of 5 parts...**
3. You will want to index 5 columns

In short - **it a lot faster** to index for a 12 length text column (in case you can't do anything to verify the user input)

Just replace the dashes out with replace() command will be fine